# What is difference between "Api" and "Restful Api"?

Tags: api, rest

Recently I've faced a question that is what's the difference between api and rest api?
Or when an endpoint is called Restful?

(is that a valid question? Is there any difference?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between REST and API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189842/what-is-difference-between-rest-and-api)

Answer (score -1):

REST is a type of API. Not all APIs are REST, but all REST services are APIs.